# Why is my input parameter unescaped when calling function from an onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, xss

For some reason when calling a js function the input is unescaped when called from an onclick event. I cannot fathom why. See the snippet below for a demonstration.

The test function is called when the page loads and when you click on the button with exactly the same input but with different results.

If someone can explain this strange behaviour you will rid me of a huge headache.

```js
function test(val){
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = val
}

test('text before script &lt;script&gt;do evil stuff here&lt;/script&gt; text after script')
```

```html
<div id = 'mydiv'>
</div>

<button onclick="test('text before script &lt;script&gt;do evil stuff here&lt;/script&gt; text after script')">
try me
</button>
```

Comment: Because the entities are decoded when they're in HTML attributes.

Comment: Inspect the button in DevTools, you'll see that they've been converted to `<>`

Comment: @Barmar It seems its only in the dev tools that it is decoded. If you inspect the page source it is still encoded

Comment: In this case you can view the frame source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *double-escape* the `<`s when called from the attribute: once for when the attribute gets put into the DOM, and once for when the handler is called.

Eg

```
<script>
```

will need to turn into

```
&lt;script&gt;
```

and then into

```
&amp;lt;script&amp;gt;
```

(escaping the ampersands)

```js
function test(val){
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = val
}

test('text before script &lt;script&gt;do evil stuff here&lt;/script&gt; text after script')
```

```html
<div id = 'mydiv'>
</div>

<button onclick="test('text before script &amp;lt;script&amp;gt;do evil stuff here 2&amp;lt;/script&amp;gt; text after script')">
try me
</button>
```

Comment: This is a good reason why **not** to use inline JavaScript.